# Antenna preamplifier design for ELF Schumann resonances receiver

Tags: operational-amplifier, low-noise-amplifier, elf

I'm interested in listening to extremely low frequency band below 100Hz, where the famous Schumann resonances reside. I will use a large T shape antenna together with a very low noise, very high impedance preamplifier. This is my current draft of the preamplifier:

[image: preamplifier schematic]

C2 is the SA102A100JARC 10pF ceramic through-hole capacitor. R2 is the SM102035007FE 5GOhm through-hole resistor. C3 is an SMD ALU electrolythic capacitor. The goal is to have a -3dB LP cutoff at 100Hz and as low as possible HP -3dB cutoff (~ 1Hz). VCC is 5 volts. The next stage would probably be a 50Hz twin T notch filter. I would appreciate if you guys can do a quick check of the circuit and maybe suggest some enchancements :) Thanks !

P.S.: R2 and C2 are through-hole because of the guard ring and easier control of the leakage current.

Comment: Get a free sim tool and simulate it.

Answer (score 1):

This will be very thermal-noise noisy. And has no ESD protection.

Consider this (from dyiAudio "simplistic NJFET RIAA") which uses a 2SKxxxx
NJFET, not the default J310

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2feHPWQ.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

Answer (score 1):

The antenna is the crucial part of the design. Typically coils up to a metre in length and located at least 100 metres from any mains power sources. [This](https://jwcn-eurasipjournals.springeropen.com/articles/10.1186/s13638-018-1157-7) might be of some help.

Votis, C.I., Tatsis, G., Christofilakis, V. et al. A new portable ELF Schumann resonance receiver: design and detailed analysis of the antenna and the analog front-end. J Wireless Com Network 2018, 155 (2018) doi:10.1186/s13638-018-1157-7